# How to handle internationalization/localization with Gatsby JS?

Tags: gatsby

I would like to publish my static site in various locals around the world with localized content.

How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I recently added a default Gatsby starter with features of multi-language url routes and browser language detection. [(demo)](https://gatsby-starter-default-intl.netlify.com/)

[gatsby-starter-default-intl](https://github.com/wiziple/gatsby-starter-default-intl)

Features:

- Localization (Multilanguage) provided by [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl).
- Automatic redirection based on user's preferred language in browser provided by [browser-lang](https://github.com/wiziple/browser-lang).
- Support multi-language url routes within a single page component. That means you don't have to create separate pages such as `pages/en/index.js` or `pages/ko/index.js`.
- Based on [gatsby-starter-default](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default) with least modification.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Demo is not SEO optimized.
Try 
curl https://gatsby-starter-default-intl.netlify.com
on your terminal

route change is happening on client (browser). Demo is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's a community plugin [gatsby-plugin-i18n](https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n) that you could *"use […] with react-intl, i18next, or any other i18n library. This plugin do not translate messages, it just creates routes for each language, and you can use different layouts for each language if you want to."* (quoting the plugin README).

Its first release is dated 30th of August 2017, so maybe you already stumbled upon it in the meantime?!

Answer (score 1):

fyi: there is a [blog post](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2017-10-17-building-i18n-with-gatsby/) describing step by step how to use that community plugin [gatsby-plugin-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-i18n) in combination with [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next) ([react-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next))

Comment: Actually this blog post is not describing the gatsby community plugin as they choose to use react-18next. But it is still a very good introduction to i18n

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, I also attempted to use [gatsby-plugin-i18n](https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n). However, my case was slightly different as I was generating all the pages in `gatsby-node.ts`, even the index and 404 pages. Although I did make it work with the plugin specified, it doesn't automatically redirect the index page to the specified pages. I was also able to query from the headless CMS using different `locales`, so it was easier in `gatsby-node.ts` to generate all the pages separately.

Once I had all the pages, I manually created an index and a 404 page in `pages` directory and from their I redirected to a localized page followed by the `locale` in the url.

For automated navigation to browser specified language page, you can use `const locale = navigator.language?.substring(0, 2)` to get the `locale` and then redirect to specified page.