# How to create indexable i18n content dynamically from a CMS in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, gatsby, contentful

In my case I am trying to create SEO ready content from Contentful pulled into Gatsby. I've tried to integrate the community i18n plugin with the Contentful example here: https://github.com/mccrodp/gatsby-contentful-i18n/pull/1

I've seen the more [general questions relating to i18n in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489980/how-to-handle-internationalization-localization-with-gatsby-js?rq=1) and the blog post [Building i18n with Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2017-10-17-building-i18n-with-gatsby/) which does not use the community plugin, nor provide a linked repository example. However, I cannot understand how to integrate the community plugin [gatsby-starter-default-i18n](https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n/tree/master/packages/gatsby-starter-default-i18n) with dynamic content via a CMS, such as the [Using Contentful Example](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-contentful).

I guess it boils down to how to manage layouts dynamically together with templates and the `gatsby.node.js` file, rather than the static example we have at the moment that does not use templates. An issue was raised here previously, on i18n plugin repo [working with gatsby-source-contentful](https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n/issues/16), but it seems inactive at the moment.

Any help greatly appreciated. I don't need to use the community plugin, just a SEO ready solution for indexed, dynamic i18n content paths. Thanks!

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n/issues/12 ?

Comment: @SébastienDubois, thanks for that issue. Yes I had already a comment on it, and extended it just now with my current thinking. Thanks for your suggestions and help with this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This involves using `node_locale` in `createPages` fn in `gatsby.node.js` to set the locale based paths. Then you can use this in combination with dynamic sources. For example, I have created starter repos for markdownRemark and Contentful:

- https://github.com/mccrodp/gatsby-starter-contentful-i18n
- https://github.com/mccrodp/gatsby-transformer-remark-i18n